# Serial Over LAN on FreeBSD with SuperMicro X9-SCM-F

Tags: freebsd, supermicro, serial

How can I setup Serial-Over-Lan (SOL) on FreeBSD with a [SuperMicro X9-SCM-F](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C202_C204/X9SCM-F.cfm) motherboard? There are a few resources out there but they contradict each other, are unclear, and don’t actually allow me to get SOL working past the boot loader.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was originally tested on FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE, but will likely work on FreeBSD 9.x, and is known to work up to at least 13.0-RELEASE. Different motherboards may have slightly different configuration, but this may still prove a useful reference.

#### BIOS Configuration

- Open the BIOS settings and navigate to “Advanced → Serial Port Console Redirection” and ensure “SOL Console Redirection” is set to “Enabled” (you do not need to enable COM1 or COM2 or Out-of-Band management).
- Open the “SOL Console Redirection Settings” and configure as follows:

  ```
  Terminal Type                        [VT-UTF8]
  Bits per second                      [115200]
  Data Bits                            [8]
  Parity                               [None]
  Stop Bits                            [1]
  Flow Control                         [None]
  VT-UTF8 Combo Key Support            [Enabled]
  Recorder Mode                        [Disabled]
  Resolution 100x31                    [Enabled]
  Legacy OS Redirection Resolution     [80x24]
  Putty KeyPad                         [VT100]
  Redirection After BIOS POST          [Always Enable]
  ```

You should only have to change “Terminal Type” to VT-UTF8 and “Bits per second” to 115200 to achieve the above configuration. Not changing the Terminal Type resulting in some issues when copy-pasting into the SOL session.

#### FreeBSD Configuration

- Boot FreeBSD and add the following lines to `/boot/loader.conf`:

  ```
  console="comconsole vidconsole"
  comconsole_speed=115200
  comconsole_port="0x3E8"
  ```

`0x3E8` is the port for COM3 (“SOL” in the BIOS settings). You can discover the possible values by inspecting `dmesg` like so:

```
$ dmesg | grep uart
uart0: <16550 or compatible> port 0x3f8-0x3ff irq 4 flags 0x10 on acpi0
uart0: console (115200,n,8,1)
uart1: <16550 or compatible> port 0x2f8-0x2ff irq 3 on acpi0
uart2: <16550 or compatible> port 0x3e8-0x3ef irq 10 on acpi0
```

If you wish to be get a login prompt (and thus be able to login) via SOL, edit `/etc/ttys` changing the following line:

```
ttyu2   "/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"   dialup  off secure
```

to

```
ttyu2   "/usr/libexec/getty std.115200" vt100   on secure
```

We change `ttyu2` because this corresponds to COM3 (since TTYs are zero-indexed and COM is not) which is what our SOL uses. If you don’t need to login (because, for example, you just need to enter a password for [GELI](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=geli&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE) during boot), you can leave `/etc/ttys` as-is.

#### Notes

Above is the minimum required to get this working. Various people (see “References” below) recommended or stated that they “needed” a slew of other settings which, for me, were not needed but did not impair SOL functionality either. Again, **the following should not be needed**, and is included for reference only.

- In `/boot/loader.conf`:

  ```
  boot_multicons="yes"
  boot_serial="yes"
  hint.uart.0.flags="0x00"
  hint.uart.2.at="isa"
  hint.uart.2.flags="0x10"
  hint.uart.2.irq="10"
  hint.uart.2.port="0x3E8"
  ```
- In `/boot.config`:

  ```
  -P
  ```

  or

  ```
  -Dh
  ```

Despite what the [FreeBSD handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/serialconsole-setup.html) seems to say, you should not need to compile a custom kernel.

#### References

Please note that many of these are wrong, out-of-date, or overzealous in setting options not actually needed. Despite that, they were helpful in arriving at the final implementation described above.

- http://www.ackstorm.org/?p=44 ([archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20140108044113/http://www.ackstorm.org/?p=44))
- http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/serialconsole-setup.html
- http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2012-June/242173.html
- http://freebsd.1045724.n5.nabble.com/IPMI-SOL-setup-on-FreeBSD-9-1-amd64-supermicro-X9SCM-F-X9CL-F-td5779729.html
- http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2013-February/thread.html#72437
- [http://www.paranoid.nl/~eilander/freebsd/ipmi/ipmicons.html](http://www.paranoid.nl/%7Eeilander/freebsd/ipmi/ipmicons.html) ([archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20150509164514/http://www.paranoid.nl/%7Emarieke/freebsd/ipmi/ipmicons.html))

Comment: Very useful info - thanks. On Supermicro X10 motherboard series, the SOL port is COM2, (0x2F8). Perhaps someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Not enough rep to comment on the answer above, so:

I run FreeBSD 9.2 and Andrew's configuration above enables SOL on COM 3 for me on X8SIL-F / X8SIE-F, from BIOS to login prompt. It is completely based on his above answer but tested on 9.2 with GENERIC kernel--thank you, Andrew!

A few notes:

- It seems to be the order of 'comconsole' or 'vidconsole' in the line "console=..." in `/boot/loader.conf`, that determines which becomes the boot console proper, and thus where the console messages (and single user prompt) appears. I could not get `/boot.config` to influence that, neither probing for keyboard, -P, or double console, -D, see `boot(8)`, had any effect--so I do not have a `/boot.config`.
- The X8SIL's BIOS settings for COM3 were spot on. I only changed the terminal type to VT-UTF8 as suggested, even though ANSI and VT100 works, too--I tested them.
- It was not necessary for me to set the irq for `uart2` in `/boot/loader.conf`. For the flags, see `uart(8)`.
- In `/dev/ttys`, I set `ttyu2` to 'insecure', because I don't want root to login over SOL (single user mode will still get you root). I suggest to set the console insecure as well.

Answer (score 0):

If someone's still unable to get the SOL output - reset the BMC, this might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, but this saved my day.

I did however need to add these to `/boot/device.hints` as without it, FreeBSD does not see the uart2 device for the SOL console.  I have a Supermicro X9SRi-3F, and the SOL console runs on COM3.  There is no way to change this, even if you disable the other two onboard serial ports.

I had to add these to fully unlock serial console support on FreeBSD 12.2

```
hint.uart.2.at="isa"
hint.uart.2.port="0x3E8"
hint.uart.2.flags="0x10"
```